# Insert a value to hidden input Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to pass a value to hidden input ?

Create form :

```
@if (isset($id))
    {!! Form::hidden('edition', $id) !!}
@endif
```

I got the form id by url like this :

```
<a href="../journal/create?edition={{$edition->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Add Journal</a>
```

( when I click Add Journal button it will shows a create form with edition id at the url)

and the controller is :

```
$id = $request->get('edition');
        $journal = Edition::findOrFail($id)->journal()->create($input);
```

The result gave me this error "`No query results for model [App\Edition].`"

Comment: Well your error says you don't have `$edition` variable in your view. So apart from passing the hidden value you don't have this variable that you're trying to use.

Comment: How to add the variable to the view ? or is there a way I can get the form id without using hidden input ?

Comment: Please add to your question your controller method that loads the view.

Comment: done @TheFallen

Comment: man, I was so dumb. I've updated the question

Comment: `No query results for model` is coming from `Edition::findOrFail($id)` - it means there is no such record in the DB.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Usually, this is used in Blade templates.

Just pass the name and value to the method.

```
{{ Form::hidden('invisible', 'secret') }}
```

This creates a very simple element which looks like the following.

```
<input name="invisible" type="hidden" value="secret">
```

To add other attributes, pass a third argument to the method. This third argument must be an array.

```
{{ Form::hidden('invisible', 'secret', array('id' => 'invisible_id')) }}
```

Now the input has an id attribute.

```
<input id="invisible_id" name="invisible" type="hidden" value="secret">
```

Check out : [Creating a Hidden Input Field](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/157/creating-a-hidden-input-field)

---

### If still not work check you project have [`Laravel Collective`](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html) installed

In controller method check

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->input('name');
}
```

Comment: tried it, gave me this error "No query results for model [App\Edition]."

Comment: Check your query first or go to **public function show** and add **dd($journal_list);** before return for check your result

Comment: What is it suppose to do ? got this result Collection {#184 ▼
  #items: []
}"

Comment: Loading the show view is just fine, I can load the journals data the belongs to an Edition

Comment: Show me your models

Comment: Journal model :                                                                                      public function edition()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Edition', 'id_edition');
    }

Comment: Edition model : public function journal()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Journal', 'id_edition');
    }

Comment: the relations is just fine as well, my problem is that how to pass the form id to hidden view in the form then pass it to controller

Comment: http://localhost/1mark/public/jurnal/create?edition=1 .. as it shows the create form url has edition id, I wanted to know how to pass this id to controller

Comment: Why you not use route **Route::get('/jurnal/create/edition/{id}', 'Method@Controller');**

Comment: Nah I was wrong, the real question is how to pass the id value to the hidden input ? I've updated the question

Comment: it's easy if you want to use **localhost/1mark/public/jurnal/create?edition=1** just type **value="<?php $_GET['id'] ?>"** and if you use route type **value="{{ Request::segment(4) }}"** 4 is your position variable you want

Comment: Tried using this Route::get('/jurnal/create/edition/{id}', 'JournalController@store'); when I call it to method "public function store(JournalRequest $request, $id)" it gave me error "Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\JurnalController::store()"

Comment: The last ones was not working either, seems like I'm having problem retrieving the id value to controller

Comment: Tried to add static id value of an existing record and it works

Comment: Can I remote to help you ?

Comment: No it's solved already, I wasn't aware that the resource controller doesn't accept any more arguments except the request instance, so I changed the method name and then rerouting everything and voila, it's working now ..

Comment: i did the form::hidden like this example but when i dd the request there is no value hiddenx

Comment: can we update the hidden input as we normally do with simple input in this blade formate ? @Jarvis

Answer (score 13):

you can do this with the help of blade 
`<input type="hidden" value="{{$user->id}}" name="user_id">`

Comment: I think this is much cleaner than other solutions.

Comment: How to add array in hidden field?