# enable input only if it matches the id in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, input

Hello I have a variable with an array of inputs
Example:
$userRestaurantsIds

```json
array:2 [▼
  0 => 12
  1 => 13
]
```

That as a result of this laravel creates inputs from all ids of the sql query
I know how to create the inputs but I need the values that are not in that array to be disabled for exampleI know how to create the inputs but I need the values that are not in that array to be disabled for example

```
<input value="13" id="tomorrow" type="checkbox" data-name="Loquillo Tienda 2" name="user_restaurants[]" checked="checked">
```

As this input has the value 13 that is in the array is enabled

```
<input value="9" (input no clickeable or hidden but in the data for the submit)  id="tomorrow" type="checkbox" data-name="Loquillo Tienda 2" name="user_restaurants[]" checked="checked">
```

But this input has a value of 9, it is enabled in check but it could not be edited because it is not in the array.

My input query on the products.blade page is this

```json
                            @foreach($allRestaurants as $ar)
                            <label>
                            <input id="tomorrow" type="checkbox" data-name="{{ $ar->name }}" name="user_restaurants[]" value="{{ $ar->id }}" @if(in_array($ar->id, $userRestaurantsIds)) checked="checked" @endif/>
                            <span>{{ $ar->name }}</span>
                            </label>
                            @endforeach
```

In summary I want that only the inputs that have the values of the array are visible and the rest remain disabled or are not visible but that they are in the submit data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert a value to hidden input Laravel Blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314789/insert-a-value-to-hidden-input-laravel-blade)

Comment: It looks like you already managed to set the `checked` attribute based on exactly that same criterion, with `@if(in_array($ar->id, $userRestaurantsIds)) checked="checked" @endif` – so what exactly is stopping you from doing the exact opposite thing with the `disabled` attribute …?

Comment: _“but that they are in the submit data”_ - then you definitively don’t want `disabled`, because disabled form items _don’t_ cause an entry in the form submission data set. Use `readonly` then, or add a class to hide them via CSS. (Un-checked checkboxes do not create an entry in the submission data set either though, so unless you set the `checked` attribute on those to begin with then, it won’t achieve much.)

Comment: How would the opposite be in laravel?
would this be?

@if(!in_array($ar->id, $userRestaurantsIds)) checked="checked" @endif

Comment: Dear @CBroe if I add a class in css the user can enter the console and make them visible and choose them? this is safe?

Comment: _Nothing_ coming from the client is ever safe. (You’d be naive to even assume that whatever input your server-side scripts receive, must have come from something like a “browser”.) Server-side validation of data is _always_ essential.

Comment: Oh I see, what do you advise me, do I need the values to be there for the submid only of readonly or css or something else?

Comment: Dear CBroe is it possible to encode that part of the input code in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Use an if statement to check whether your value is in the array or not. If it's not in the array, set display to none. This will then be in the resulting data, unless someone were to edit the DOM.

```html
<input value="9" id="tomorrow" type="checkbox" data-name="Loquillo Tienda 2" name="user_restaurants[]" checked="checked" @if(! in_array(9, $userRestaurantsIds)) style="display:none;" @endif>
```

Second option of approach would be a hidden input

```html
@if(! in_array(9, $userRestaurantsIds)) 
    <input type="hidden" value="9" name="user_restaurants[]">
@endif>
```

If you go with the first option, do make sure it has the `checked` attribute, else it won't be in your data.

Comment: Hello dear both options are unsafe if doom is changed.
Do you have any ideas on how to improve the code or obfuscate it so that it is not edited?

Comment: Well, you wanted it to be in the request data. This data has to be in the DOM somewhere, whether it's in a route, a (hidden) form input or attached with JS on submit. If you need that data and you can't validate it, then just retrieve it in the backens the same way you retrieved it in the first place to share it with the fronted, or store it in the session.